# Query two tables then output in one column

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, mysqli

i want to query two tables then give the result in one column eg

```
table1

id   name  town 
23   john  nyc
34   mark  ATl
44   ali   Dubs


table2

cno reg
45  kln
47  dsgd
28  wer
```

the output i expect is

```
newcolumn
   23
   34
   44
   45
   47
   28
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use MySQL [UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html).

```
SELECT id FROM table 1

UNION 

SELECT cno AS id FROM table2
```

In `UNION`, you can combine results from two or more database tables.

But, it needs that the selected columns should be similar.

For example, if you are fetching 5 fields from one SQL and 6 fields from another SQL.

And making `UNION` of these two queries, it will not work.

Above SQL works because, you are selecting one column each from SQLs.

Comment: thanks this works.. i was missing the second part where you also rename the column cno to id

Comment: @dannjoroge . . . You should use `UNION ALL` unless you specifically want to incur the overhead of removing duplicates.